# Submit an app to app-store build with ios 8.4 SDK and run it on a device with iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9

I know that it's possible to build an app with xcode 6.4 and then deploy it on a device running iOS 9 with TestFlight or any other deployment tool. The question is if it's possible with apples app store. Or more precisely, when will apple force us to switch to the iOS 9 SDK when submitting to the app store? Will it be September? Octobre? 2015?

Many thanks!
TK

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking people to guess when Apple may or may not make a policy change.

Comment: I'm not asking to guess :), I'm asking if anyone knows the policy or if there is one. And there were certain deadlines before like with the 64bit conversion. Maybe apple announced the same for iOS 9 and I missed it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over time, Apple sets the minimum version of XCode that you can submit with, but the "SDK" requirement is dependent on the APIs that you are actually using.

The Deployment Target version is the minimum iOS version that your app supports, and you can set the target version less than the latest version. This affects the user at download/install time. If their device does not meet the minimum, they won't be able to download and install the app.

The minimum Deployment Target that you can set in XCode also increases over time with new releases of XCode. In that case, you may have some deadlines to beat to provide updates for the app that support older iOS versions. According to wikipedia, XCode 7 will allow a minimum iOS 5.1.1 deployment target, though you may have to set it manually.

Answer (score 3):

There 2 things to note:

**The iOS SDK version**

This version is set in your projects, it lets you use the API of this version.

**The minimum iOS Version**

This is the minimum version targeted for the device.

---

It is more about the device limitation, for example iPhone 4 will not run ios9.

And the iOS SDK version available is based on your version of xCode.

Comment: Thx! But you can set the SDK in Xcode to older SDKs. So you could use Xcode 7 with SDK 8.4(5). But if I understand your comment correctly, I can develop and deploy my apps with Xcode 6 even after apple released ios 9, correct?

Comment: Apple releases sdk in advance so developer will have the apps ready for ios9 release. You need to perform checks be fore using ios9 feature if u want to target older devices

Comment: Eventually, Apple will require a Base SDK of iOS 9. Of course the Deployment Target can be much lower.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely candidate is February 1, 2016, if you trust that Apple will behave as previous years.

Follow https://developer.apple.com/news/ in your RSS-reader to get updates. The update for last year was released on October 20, https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a.

They made an exception for app updates last year, see https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=04082015a, but it is unlikely they will make the same exception this time.